# How to set up Jacoco with activator/sbt?

Tags: sbt, jacoco, typesafe-activator

I found [JaCoCo Code Coverage plug-in for sbt](https://github.com/sbt/jacoco4sbt) that seems perfect for my needs, but I'm having issues setting it up. The wiki indicates only two lines need to be added to `project/plugins.sbt` and `build.sbt`, but I'm getting the following error when I execute `sbt jacoco:cover`:

```
bhan@bhan-laptop:~/src/connectifier$ sbt jacoco:cover
[info] Loading project definition from /home/bhan/src/connectifier/project
[info] Set current project to connectifier (in build file:/home/bhan/src/connectifier/)
[info] Set current project to connectifier (in build file:/home/bhan/src/connectifier/)
[error] No such setting/task
[error] jacoco:cover
[error]

bhan@benhan-laptop:~/src/connectifier$ sbt about
[info] Loading project definition from /home/bhan/src/connectifier/project
[info] Set current project to connectifier (in build file:/home/bhan/src/connectifier/)
[info] Set current project to connectifier (in build file:/home/bhan/src/connectifier/)
[info] This is sbt 0.13.6
[info] The current project is {file:/home/bhan/src/connectifier/}frontend 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.11.1
[info] Available Plugins: sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin, sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin, sbt.plugins.CorePlugin, sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin, play.Play, play.PlayJava, play.PlayScala, play.twirl.sbt.SbtTwirl, com.typesafe.sbt.jse.SbtJsEngine, com.typesafe.sbt.jse.SbtJsTask, com.typesafe.sbt.web.SbtWeb, com.typesafe.sbt.webdriver.SbtWebDriver, com.typesafe.sbt.rjs.SbtRjs, com.typesafe.sbt.less.SbtLess, com.typesafe.sbt.digest.SbtDigest, com.typesafe.sbt.gzip.SbtGzip, com.typesafe.sbteclipse.plugin.EclipsePlugin, org.sbtidea.SbtIdeaPlugin, com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager, de.johoop.jacoco4sbt.JacocoPlugin
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.10.4
```

Am I missing any additional setup? I'm not very familiar with sbt/activator, but I'm under the impression that sbt will automatically download the plugin from the relevant repo and that I don't need to manually clone the git repo. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** Trying to reproduce the issue in my sample didn't work out whatsoever. The documentation of jacoco4sbt plugin worked fine.

It'd really be helpful to see `build.sbt` and `project/plugins.sbt`.

The build seems a Play project with sbt-native-packager installed (amongst the other plugins).

Here's how it works in my build:

```
➜  sandbox  activator new jacoco4sbt-play play-scala

Fetching the latest list of templates...

OK, application "jacoco4sbt-play" is being created using the "play-scala" template.

To run "jacoco4sbt-play" from the command line, "cd jacoco4sbt-play" then:
/Users/jacek/sandbox/jacoco4sbt-play/activator run

To run the test for "jacoco4sbt-play" from the command line, "cd jacoco4sbt-play" then:
/Users/jacek/sandbox/jacoco4sbt-play/activator test

To run the Activator UI for "jacoco4sbt-play" from the command line, "cd jacoco4sbt-play" then:
/Users/jacek/sandbox/jacoco4sbt-play/activator ui
➜  sandbox  cd jacoco4sbt-play
➜  jacoco4sbt-play  tree
.
|-- LICENSE
|-- README
|-- activator
|-- activator-launch-1.2.10.jar
|-- app
|   |-- controllers
|   |   `-- Application.scala
|   `-- views
|       |-- index.scala.html
|       `-- main.scala.html
|-- build.sbt
|-- conf
|   |-- application.conf
|   `-- routes
|-- project
|   |-- build.properties
|   `-- plugins.sbt
|-- public
|   |-- images
|   |   `-- favicon.png
|   |-- javascripts
|   |   `-- hello.js
|   `-- stylesheets
|       `-- main.css
`-- test
    |-- ApplicationSpec.scala
    `-- IntegrationSpec.scala

10 directories, 17 files
➜  jacoco4sbt-play  cat project/plugins.sbt
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.4")

// web plugins

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("de.johoop" % "jacoco4sbt" % "2.1.6")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "0.8.0-M1")
➜  jacoco4sbt-play  cat build.sbt
name := """jacoco4sbt-play"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
  ws
)

jacoco.settings
➜  jacoco4sbt-play  sbt jacoco:cover
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/sandbox/jacoco4sbt-play/project
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/jacoco4sbt-play/project/}jacoco4sbt-play-build...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] downloading http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.8.0-M1/jars/sbt-native-packager.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-native-packager;0.8.0-M1!sbt-native-packager.jar (5065ms)
[info] Done updating.
[info] Set current project to jacoco4sbt-play (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/jacoco4sbt-play/)
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/jacoco4sbt-play/}root...
[info] Resolving org.jacoco#org.jacoco.agent;0.7.1.201405082137 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 5 Scala sources and 1 Java source to /Users/jacek/sandbox/jacoco4sbt-play/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[info] Compiling 2 Scala sources to /Users/jacek/sandbox/jacoco4sbt-play/target/scala-2.11/test-classes...
[info] ApplicationSpec
[info]
[info] Application should
[info] + send 404 on a bad request
[info] + render the index page
[info]
[info] Total for specification ApplicationSpec
[info] Finished in 22 ms
[info] 2 examples, 0 failure, 0 error
[info] IntegrationSpec
[info]
[info] Application should
[info] + work from within a browser
[info]
[info] Total for specification IntegrationSpec
[info] Finished in 22 ms
[info] 1 example, 0 failure, 0 error
[info] Passed: Total 3, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 3
[info]
[info] ------- Jacoco Coverage Report --------
[info]
[info] Lines: 57.5% (>= required 0.0%) covered, 34 of 80 missed, OK
[info] Instructions: 71.94% (>= required 0.0%) covered, 523 of 1864 missed, OK
[info] Branches: 27.78% (>= required 0.0%) covered, 26 of 36 missed, OK
[info] Methods: 81.94% (>= required 0.0%) covered, 41 of 227 missed, OK
[info] Complexity: 76.73% (>= required 0.0%) covered, 57 of 245 missed, OK
[info] Class: 57.14% (>= required 0.0%) covered, 12 of 28 missed, OK
[info] Check /Users/jacek/sandbox/jacoco4sbt-play/target/scala-2.11/jacoco for detail report
[info]
[success] Total time: 16 s, completed Sep 23, 2014 10:45:36 PM
```

It works fine. They're correct to expect people to have these two lines in a build to set up the plugin properly.

I can see that `de.johoop.jacoco4sbt.JacocoPlugin` is indeed listed in the plugins section in `sbt about`.

I've got a very similar set of plugins in the build, too.

```
➜  jacoco4sbt-play  sbt about
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/sandbox/jacoco4sbt-play/project
[info] Set current project to jacoco4sbt-play (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/jacoco4sbt-play/)
[info] This is sbt 0.13.5
[info] The current project is {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/jacoco4sbt-play/}root 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.11.1
[info] Available Plugins: sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin, sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin, sbt.plugins.CorePlugin, sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin, play.Play, play.PlayJava, play.PlayScala, play.twirl.sbt.SbtTwirl, com.typesafe.sbt.jse.SbtJsEngine, com.typesafe.sbt.jse.SbtJsTask, com.typesafe.sbt.web.SbtWeb, com.typesafe.sbt.webdriver.SbtWebDriver, com.typesafe.sbt.coffeescript.SbtCoffeeScript, com.typesafe.sbt.less.SbtLess, com.typesafe.sbt.jshint.SbtJSHint, com.typesafe.sbt.rjs.SbtRjs, com.typesafe.sbt.digest.SbtDigest, com.typesafe.sbt.mocha.SbtMocha, com.typesafe.sbteclipse.plugin.EclipsePlugin, net.virtualvoid.sbt.graph.Plugin, com.timushev.sbt.updates.UpdatesPlugin, org.sbtidea.SbtIdeaPlugin, com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager, de.johoop.jacoco4sbt.JacocoPlugin
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.10.4
```

With the following `build.sbt` in your project, note the last line in the file:

```
lazy val data = project

lazy val avro = project

lazy val frontend = (project in file("frontend"))
    .enablePlugins(PlayJava, SbtWeb)
    .dependsOn(data % "test->test;compile->compile").aggregate(data)
    .dependsOn(avro).aggregate(avro)

// JaCoCo (java) test coverage
jacoco.settings

// Scoverage (scala) test coverage
ScoverageSbtPlugin.instrumentSettings

// Switch to the frontend project on startup
onLoad in Global := { Command.process("project frontend", _: State) } compose (onLoad in Global).value
```

At the last line you're switching to project `frontend` that doesn't have the jacoco4sbt plugin enabled.

Execute `project` command to see what project you're in. I'm sure it's going to be `frontend`.

```
> project
[info] frontend (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/jacoco4sbt-play/)
```

My answer considered a single project build while you're working with 3-module build with only the implicit root project set up with jacoco4sbt.

The simplest solution is to create `build.sbt` inside `frontend` directory with the following:

```
jacoco.settings
```

When you do `reload` (or stop and start sbt), `jacoco:cover` should work fine.

```
> project
[info] frontend (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/jacoco4sbt-play/)

> jacoco:cover
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/jacoco4sbt-play/}frontend...
[info] Resolving org.jacoco#org.jacoco.agent;0.7.1.201405082137 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info]
[info] ------- Jacoco Coverage Report --------
[info]
[info] Lines: 0% (>= required 0.0%) covered, 0 of 0 missed, OK
[info] Instructions: 0% (>= required 0.0%) covered, 0 of 0 missed, OK
[info] Branches: 0% (>= required 0.0%) covered, 0 of 0 missed, OK
[info] Methods: 0% (>= required 0.0%) covered, 0 of 0 missed, OK
[info] Complexity: 0% (>= required 0.0%) covered, 0 of 0 missed, OK
[info] Class: 0% (>= required 0.0%) covered, 0 of 0 missed, OK
[info] Check /Users/jacek/sandbox/jacoco4sbt-play/frontend/target/scala-2.10/jacoco for detail report
[info]
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Sep 26, 2014 5:35:06 PM
```

Comment: Thanks for explicit instructions. I'm not familiar with sbt/activator and was missing the `new jacoco4sbt-play play-scala`.


Activator test seems to be working, but I still get the following error with `jacoco:cover`: `Not a valid key: cover (similar: resolvers, compilers, deliver)`

Comment: Still having some issues, here's the build.sbt and plugins.sbt: http://pastebin.com/iC6ku385

Comment: See my update. It should resolve your issue. Thanks for accepting the answer!